# RVM - Warning! PATH is not properly set up

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am having trouble with my RVM - I keep getting error messages telling me that PATH is not correctly set up.

First off, any of of this sounds like it it's coming from a complete noob, that's because it is. There have been some similar threads that I've been looking at, but nothing has helped me fix the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

When I run `rvm get head` and I get the message:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.0'.
```

I've tried running `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles` and restarted the terminal- no help.

Running `rvm use ruby-2.1.0` also does not do anything, even in the current shell session.

When I run `rvm --debug get head` I noticed this:

```
step> 'update_gemsets_install_rvm' started
Installing rvm gem in 1 gemsetsERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/cache/rvm-1.11.3.8.gem
Installing gem-wrappers gem in 2 gemsetsERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/cache/gem-wrappers-1.2.1.gemERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/cache/gem-wrappers-1.2.1.gem
```

**My research thus far leads me to believe that the problem is somewhere in my bash_profile**

I've been referencing [this thread](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2272), it seems like we have similar issue but I can't figure out what I would need to change/remove in my bash_profile to remedy the problem.

Here are the contents of my bash_profile:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]]; then
  source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm;
fi
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/bin
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Did you *READ* the *ENTIRE* [RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install)? Don't read other pages, don't read blogs, etc. Follow what the authors of the tool say to do.

Comment: Good advice. I've been looking all over the internet for info on this and have read the RVM troubleshooting page but NOT the install page - thanks! I'll see if this helps.

Comment: @theTinMan offers good advice, but the best place to get help with RVM is at the [rvm channel of freenode Irc](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm).  Among others, RVM's creator, Wayne Seguin, hangs out there and is happy to help.  Before making your appearance, though, check your path and learn how to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are referencing two problems in your question: the first one is answered by @the-tin-man, the other is a permissions problem:

> Permission denied - /Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/cache/gem-wrappers-1.2.1.gemERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)

You can fix it using:

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

---

Remember, always read the instructions/warnings/errors printed by RVM, they are there to help you.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not going to tell you how to do it, because you need to learn to understand what you're doing when you work with environment variables.

At the command-line, enter:

```
echo $PATH
```

RVM's path information should be first in the chain.

Look at your PATH manipulations:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]]; then
  source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm;
fi
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/mbauer/.rvm/src/rvm/bin
```

Do you see why it isn't first in the chain? (Also, do you see some general confusion showing you don't know how PATH works?)

I'd recommend taking some time to learn how environment variables and the PATH work. Read through the RVM installation page, then figure out how to make RVM's initialization appear first in the PATH.

Comment: I appreciate the help (or non-help in this case). I took your advice and did some reading and changed my code to clean up some of the redundancy and syntax errors and moved the RVM info to be the last thing in the file and that fixed my issue.

Comment: Is this why it works? "Ensure that RVM is sourced after any path settings as RVM and manipulates the path. If you don't do this, RVM may not work as expected."

Comment: While you might not like it, it seems to have helped the OP, by instigating learning how the environment worked, which was my intention. I don't like handing out fish because it doesn't help the other person avoid the problem the next time. I'd rather they learn how to fish so they avoid repeating the problem, and they can teach others how to avoid the problem too.

Comment: This answer helped me much. I found that I had some heroku path info appearing prior to RVM when running `echo $PATH`. A little more research found I had to run `gem uninstall heroku` and then `source .bashrc; source .bash_profile`.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. That's the goal!

Comment: Yeah, that's a little bit self righteous. Typically it's question and answer here. That format has worked very well. It's not question, followed by superfluous explanation on why I'm not going to give you the answer because if you teach a man to fish blah blah.

Comment: Some posters need a nudge to learn more than we can write in an answer. Teaching, which is really what occurs here, happens in many different ways. It's up to the teacher to decide how to present it. You are free to disagree, however I'd suggest doing so after having spent a lot of time working to provide answers to others here.

Comment: @theTinMan Cheers! I was busy, but I'm glad I took the time out to learn about the PATH variable and how to fix the issue